# Can't run python script from command line NO MODULE NAMED project_name

Tags: python, command-line

I'm trying to run my python script from my command line , I can do it just find in Jupyter however I'm getting this:

```
(.venv) E:\descriptionExtractor>python -m description_exctractor
E:\descriptionExtractor\.venv\Scripts\python.exe: No module named description_exctractor
```

here's my project structure :
[image: structure]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

description_extractor is not a python file (note it does not have the .py extension). To launch it from the command line you will need to try launching a python file.

Comment: description_extractor is a directory, it has all the other files (main, skill_extractor..) and the data directory.

Comment: then try python -m description_extractor main.py. or __main__.py if that is what you have called it

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to put **init**.py on the descricption_extractor directory

```
descricption_extractor
|-__init__.py
|-"__main__".py
|-cleanup.py
|-skill_extractor
```

What is that "**main**".py for?

Comment: it's the main file where I call other methods and parse the input arguments. Should I put that in the init file?